# Azure kubernetes - How to debug the application deployed?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am planning to deploy the Asp.net core based applications on azure kubernetes, how do I debug the deployed application using either VScode or Visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use **Snapshot Debugger** for Azure Kubernetes.  The Snapshot Debugger takes a snapshot of your in-production apps when code that you're interested in executes. To instruct the debugger to take a **snapshot**, you set **snappoints** and **logpoints** in your code. The debugger lets you see exactly what went wrong, without impacting traffic of your production application. The Snapshot Debugger can help you dramatically reduce the time it takes to resolve issues that occur in production environments.

Snappoints and logpoints are similar to breakpoints, but unlike breakpoints, snappoints don't halt the application when hit. Typically, capturing a snapshot at a snappoint takes 10-20 milliseconds.

You will have to:

- start the Snapshot Debugger
- set a snappoint and view a snapshot
- set a logpoint

Take a look: [debug-live-azure-kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-kubernetes?view=vs-2019), [vs-azure-kubernetes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/kubernetes).